# Using get_followers function in R but getting different results from all other laptops used

Tags: r, append, rstudio

I tried using the following code

```
library(rtweet)

D <- c()
for(u in c("OneNaziq", "AzimRidzuan_", "pais_10")) {
  D <- rbind(D, get_followers(u, n= "all", page = "-1", parse = TRUE, as_double = FALSE, token = NULL))
}

nrow(D)
```

I ran it on different device it gave me the right answer (2,193), although it may increase a bit since users can have new followers. I tried it then on my laptop and it keeps giving me large numbers such as 12,451. I think its really weird, what may cause this?